# Extract a named value from pair in a comma separate list

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to extract the value of a variable by name (`var1`,`var2`, or `var3`) from a string of comma separated variables in bash:

```
var1=foo,var2=bar,var3=baz
```

I would also like to protect against the case that duplicates exist since the variable is set in an upstream script. In the event there exists a duplicate variables I would like to return the value of the first instance only. So the following example would return `0`:

```
var1=0,var2=baz,var3=foo,var1=2
```

I would like to restrict the value to one of 0, 1 or 2. So, validate using something like `[0-2]{1}`.

Example String:

```
export labels="zone_index=1,node_type=infra,customer=internal"
```

My solution which seems to work but seems rather kludgy:

```
echo "$labels" | grep -oE -m1 'zone_index=[0-2]{1}' | cut -f2 -d= | head -n 1
```

Which will output `1` from the example string. Is there a more elegant and/or robust solution?

Comment: You should consider upvoting(`^`) and accepting the answer, if it solved your problem

Comment: I have upvoted the answer as it's certainly useful and I'll accept the answer when I've confirmed it solves my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any third party tools to make this work, just the native shell built-ins would be sufficient. The shell does provide a built-in regex support with its `~` operator (from bash `v3.0` onwards)

```
re='zone_index=([[:digit:]]{1,}).*'

if [[ $labels =~ $re ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

This regex will work for all the cases you've listed.

- For the case when when the search string occurring in the first

  ```
  labels="zone_index=1,node_type=infra,customer=internal"
  [[ $labels =~ $re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  1
  ```
- For the case when when the search string is duplicated

  ```
  labels="zone_index=1,node_type=infra,zone_index=2,customer=internal"
  [[ $labels =~ $re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  1
  ```
- For the case when when the search string is not in the start

  ```
  labels="node_type=infra,customer=internal,zone_index=2"
  [[ $labels =~ $re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  2
  ```